# How to display all Data form oData

Tags: odata, sapui5

With the oData i get about 100 Entries for equipments. The goal is that in my application all entries coming from the oData are displayed. Problem is only the first about 50 entries are shown. How can I solve this? is there somthing to do in my View?

```
    <mvc:View controllerName="zppb.bde.equi.ZP_EquList.controller.Main" xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc" displayBlock="true" xmlns="sap.m">
    <Shell id="shell">
        <App id="idAppMain">
            <pages>
                <Page id="page" title="{i18n>title}">
                    <content>
                        <Table id="idEquipmentTable" items="{MultiInfoSet>/}">
                            <headerToolbar>
                                <Toolbar>
                                    <Button icon="sap-icon://filter" press="onFilterListPress"/>
                                </Toolbar>
                            </headerToolbar>

                            <items>
                                <ColumnListItem type="Navigation" visible="true">
                                    <cells>
.
.
                                    </cells>
                                </ColumnListItem>
                            </items>
                        </Table>
                    </content>
                </Page>
            </pages>
        </App>
    </Shell>
</mvc:View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, the preferred way would be to use the `growing` functionality, where the user scrolls down the table and it'll load more lines when they approach the end of the current list.

Not many changes required:

```
<Table 
    id="idEquipmentTable" 
    items="{MultiInfoSet>/}"
    growing="true"
    growingThreshold="100"
    growingScrollToLoad="true">
```

There are a few other options if your list has a relatively low number of items and you do not want the user to scroll.

You'll find more information on this via the design guidelines: [Responsive Table - Fiori Design Guidelines](https://experience.sap.com/fiori-design-web/responsive-table/)